# Controller loads 2 times if $location.path() changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm facing a distrubing issue with my website. I'm using angular and typescript for development, the problem is : When a user logs in successfully, i'll redirect him to another page like " dashboard" , or "parentDashboard".
If i put a `debugger` on controller's constructor on `parentDashboard` or `dashboard` i see that the breakpoint is hit 2 times. I'm using `$location.path('url')` to redirect him.
This bug occurs only if i redirect him from login page. If i reload , for example `dashboard` page, that breakpoint is hit once.

This is the `router`:

```
.state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: '/app/login/login.partial.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                label: 'Login'
            },

 .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/dashboard.partial.html',             
            controller: 'DashboardController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        }) //etc.....
```

**NOTE:** I don't have `data-ng-controller` tag in none of the pages. I found that will be a problem for multiple loads.

I don't know how to figure this.

If other sourcecode needed, i'll edit my question. Thanks

```
 function initRouter($locationProvider: angular.ILocationProvider,
                    $urlRouterProvider: angular.ui.IUrlRouterProvider,
                    $stateProvider: angular.ui.IStateProvider) {       


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');        
    $stateProvider
```

Comment: why not to use $state.go('dashboard')? ...

Comment: i dont have any $state.go on my login typescript controller.

Comment: do you use html5 urls or the one with `#`?

Comment: are you using ui-router?

Comment: angular-ui-router, yeah. i edited with my app.config file constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention on trailing slash using $location.path('url').

```
$location.path('dashboard/')
```

may explain such behaviour.